# Pagination doesn't work with JpaPagingItemReader and jpql request in spring batch

Tags: postgresql, jpa, pagination, spring-batch, partitioning

I have a problem that I cannot resolve. I use PostGreSql and Spring batch and in particular the jpaPagingItemReader to read in my database with pagination in JPA.
To optimize performance, I also use a partitioner to read my database in partition. So each partition will use the jpaPagingItemReader to read the associated interval from the database. Since my base ids are not continuous, the partitioner creates partitions with lists of ids.

So the JpaPagingItemReader does a
`SELECT c FROM Entity c WHERE c.id IN: ids`
with a **pageSize (10)** and a **parameterValues** ​​containing ids to the list of ids given by the partition.
The value of my pageSize is equal to the value of my chunk.

This is where my problem comes in, which is the following.
My partition may contain a very large id list so I sometimes get the error `"java.io.IOException: Tried to send an out-of-range integer as a 2-byte value"`
Which makes sense since I technically exceed the max value allowed by PostGreSql in a resultSet.
What I do not understand is **that pagination should avoid this problem as I put a value of 10 to the pagesize of my JpaPagingItemReader**.

On the other hand for the same partition list when my JpaPagingItemReader takes a native query like `SELECT c FROM Entity c WHERE c.id IN (id1, id2, id3, ..., idn)`, **with the same pagesize (10)**, the batch starts well and the processing is done without the PostGreSql error.

It's as if pagination doesn't work on a jpql but rather on a nativesql.

Possible that I was wrong in my analysis.

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the issue is not related to the pagination nor to the response size, but to the request itself. PostgreSql has a limit on number of bind variables per statement (32767) and it's being exceeded by the IN clause. You could solve it by limiting the partition size.

Comment: Yes I know PostgreSql has a per query variable limit (32767).
But shouldn't setting a size for a page limit the number of variables in a query?

As a reminder, this problem only appears when the queryString of the JpaPagingItemReader is a jpql, not the sql.

And why the problem does not arise when I use a native query with a partition having a size larger than the limit set by PostgreSql?

Comment: Why should the size of the page limit the number of variables? They are unrelated. What if some of the variables are not present in the DB?

Comment: As for my understanding the problem does not show up with the "native query" becouse the ids are included directly in the query, so there is no binding involved.